# Delete list of files in folder which is older than x days, python

Tags: python

I am trying to delete files after a 90 day retention period, and folders after a 15 day retention period. I have stored the paths in a  `config.txt` file that looks like this:

```
[My Config]
path1 = C:\Users\mywork\pa\config\*.xml
path2 = C:\Users\mywork\data\unittest\*.csv
path3 = C:\Users\mywork\data\inttest\*.csv
path4 = C:\Users\mywork\logs
```

I am trying to convert the number of days into seconds, get the `ctime` from the `os.stat(path)` method using the attribute `st_ctime`. Then I compare the `ctime` with the time previously calculated. If the result is greater than the desired days of the user, it checks whether it is a file or folder. If it is a file, use the `os.remove(path)` and otherwise use the `shutil.rmtree()` method:

```
import os
import shutil
import time
import glob
import configparser

def main():
    # initializing the count
    deleted_folders_count = 0
    deleted_files_count = 0

    configParser = configparser.RawConfigParser()
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read_file(open(r'C:\Users\PycharmProjects\untitled\config.txt'))

    # specify the path
    path = [config.get('My Config', 'path1'), config.get('My Config', 'path2'), config.get('My Config', 'path3')]
    print(path)
    
    folder_retn_days = 15
    log_retn_days = 90

    # converting days to seconds
    # time.time() returns current time in seconds
    folder_seconds = time.time() - (folder_retn_days * 24 * 60 * 60)
    log_seconds = time.time() - (log_retn_days * 24 * 60 * 60)

    for idx, word in enumerate(path):
         print(word)
         files = glob.glob(word)

                 
         def remove_file(files):

             # removing the file
             if not os.remove(files):

                 # success message
                 print(f"{files} is removed successfully")

             else:

                 # failure message
                 print(f"Unable to delete the {files}"
                  def remove_folder(files):

             # removing the folder
             if not shutil.rmtree(files):

                 # success message
                 print(f"{files} is removed successfully")

             else:

                 # failure message
                 print(f"Unable to delete the {files}")

         def get_file_or_folder_age(files):

             # getting ctime of the file/folder
             # time will be in seconds
             ctime = os.stat(files).st_ctime

             # returning the time
             return ctime
        
         if folder_seconds >= get_file_or_folder_age(files):
             print(files)
             #remove_files(files)
             #deleted_folders_count += 1
```

I am stuck here. While printing files, it is giving this error:

```
   ctime = os.stat(files).st_ctime
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not list
```

I tried many things, but am getting the same error.

Comment: `files` is indeed a list according to the code you've shared. You need to iterate over the list of files for the operation you have in mind to be performed.

Comment: Please make sure to paste the correct code. This one is full of syntax errors and fails way earlier. Also post the full error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but as the error indicates [`stat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat) takes a single path, not a list of paths. So you have to call it for each path:

```
def get_file_or_folder_age(file):

    # getting ctime of the file/folder
    # time will be in seconds
    ctime = os.stat(file).st_ctime

    # returning the time
    return ctime

for path in files:
    if folder_seconds >= get_file_or_folder_age(file):
        print(files)  # Or other action you'd like to take.
```

I think you will run into other problems, but that is your proximal one.

Answer (score 0):

You pass `files` into `os.stats`, which is a list of files retrieved from using `glob.glob`. `os.stats` requires a path, not a list (you can refer to this document here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat).

As your requirements, I figure that you are trying to get the latest modified time of a list of files. In that case, try the following code snippet:

```
import os

def get_last_modified_time(files: list):
     return max([os.stat(file).st_ctime for file in files])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use os.scandir and fnmatch to get the same result

```
import datetime, os, fnmatch

path = "C:\\temp\\*.csv"

cutoff_date = (datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=90)).timestamp()
dirname = os.path.dirname(path)

delete_list = [ f.name for f in os.scandir(dirname) if f.is_file() 
             and f.stat().st_mtime > cutoff_date 
             and fnmatch.fnmatch(dirname + "\\" + f.name, path) ]
```